# ¿Cómo hacer esta tarea usando fichero y diccionarios?

Tags: python, spyder

tengo que escribir un diccionario en un fichero y no se cómo.
Mi diccionario es el siguiente:

```
SR7: {(3, 4): 20, (1, 1):81}
TR8: {(2, 1): 6}
MB10: {(9, 4): 20, (2, 1):1, (5, 6): 100}
```

LLamé elemento a SR7, TR8, MB10
y el fichero me lo debería devolver así:

```
3, 4, SR7, 20
1, 1, SR7, 81
2, 1, TR8, 6
9, 4, MB10, 20
2, 1, MB10, 1
5, 6, MB10, 100
```

Había pensado algo así:

```
fichero = open(filename, 'w')
for elemento in diccionario:
    for key, val in dicicionario.items():
        fichero.write(str(key)+","+ elemento +","+str(val))
fichero.close()
```

Pero no me funciona, además el programa debe añadir la extensión .txt al fichero y no sé que hacer para que se añada esa extensión.

Answer (score 0):

En el segundo for debes iterar sobre el diccionario anidado no sobre el diccionario padre como haces ahora, es decir, en todo caso debe ser:

```
for key, val in diccionario[elemento]
```

Por otro lado, `str(key)` te retorna "(3, 4)" no "3, 4". Además te falta agregar el salto de linea, ni `write` ni `writelines` lo agregan por ti.

Para la extensión, si `filename` es solo el nombre del fichero y no una ruta, basta con usar formateo de cadenas y agregar el `.txt` al nombre.

```
filename =  "test"
diccionario = {"SR7": {(3, 4): 20, (1, 1):81},
               "TR8": {(2, 1): 6},
               "MB10": {(9, 4): 20, (2, 1):1, (5, 6): 100}
               }


filename = f"{filename}.txt" if not filename.endswith(".txt") else filename
with open(filename, 'w') as fichero:
    for elemento, nested_dict in diccionario.items():
        for key, val in nested_dict.items():
            fichero.write(f"{', '.join((*map(str, key), elemento, str(val)))}\n")
```

**`test.txt`**

```
3, 4, SR7, 20
1, 1, SR7, 81
2, 1, TR8, 6
9, 4, MB10, 20
2, 1, MB10, 1
5, 6, MB10, 100
```

Se usa una coma y un espacio de separadores como en tu resultado esperado, si solo quieres la coma cambia la cadena de `join`:

```
fichero.write(f"{','.join((*map(str, key), elemento, str(val)))}\n")
```